# how to find Elements from array which makes sum equals to given value

Tags: arrays

the lowest number of integers in the array that sums up the given number. The program should ask a user to input array of integers (“Input Array”) and the required sum (“Required Sum”). The output (“Output”) should list the lowest number of integers from the input array that sums up the “Required Sum”.  Refer to examples given below.

Example:

Input Array : [10, 0, -1, 20, 25, 30]
Required Sum: 45
Output: [20, 25]

Required Sum: 59
Output: [10, -1, 20, 30]

Required Sum: 60
Output: [10, 20, 30]

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
                int arr[]={10, 0, -1, 20, 25, 30};

                int sum=59 ,temp=0;

                for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

                    for(int j=i;j<arr.length;j++){


                    if(arr[i]>arr[j]){

                        temp=arr[i];
                        arr[i]=arr[j];
                        arr[j]=temp;

                    }
                  }
                }

                for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                    System.out.println(arr[i]);
                  }

              for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

                    for(int j=i;j<arr.length-1;j++){

                        if(arr[i]+arr[j]==sum){

                            System.out.println(arr[i]+","+arr[j]);

                            break;
                             }


                        else {
                            for(int k=j+1;k<arr.length-2;k++){

                                if(arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k]==sum){

                                    System.out.println(arr[i]+","+arr[j]+","+arr[k]);

                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                     }

                  }
```

Comment: Where is your code, so we can understand what language you are working on ?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework assignment.  SO is not a code writing service or a homework service.  If you post your code and show us you're doing the work, but can't get it right, we can help you with specific coding issues.

Answer (score 0):

public class SumofArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr[] = { 10, 0, -1, 20, 25, 30 };

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter the sum:");

    int sum = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
    }

    ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList();

    int y = 0;
    int l = arr.length - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++, l--) {

        for (int j = 1 + i; j < arr.length; j++) {

            for (int k = 1 + j; k < arr.length; k++){

                if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum) {

                    arraylist.clear();
                    arraylist.add(arr[i]);
                    arraylist.add(arr[j]);

                }

                else if (arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] == sum) {

                    arraylist.clear();
                    arraylist.add(arr[i]);
                    arraylist.add(arr[j]);
                    arraylist.add(arr[k]);


                } 
                else if (arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] + arr[l] == sum) {

                    arraylist.clear();
                    arraylist.add(arr[i]);
                    arraylist.add(arr[j]);
                    arraylist.add(arr[k]);
                    arraylist.add(arr[l]);


                       }

                }
          }
    }

   System.out.println(arraylist);
```

}
}